# Change ASP .mdb access to DSN Less Connection?

Tags: asp-classic, connection-string

I have an old ASP site (written a long time ago by a former employee) that connects to a 2003 ODBC database using DSN. The servers have been updated by our hosts to 2008, and we can no longer use ODBC so I have to make the connections DSN-Less.

Unfortunately I have very little knowledge of ASP, and database connections through ASP. I wonder if anybody can help me change the code to connect to the Access database without ODBC?

I think it connects using this code:

```vbs
<%
' Get current name of region and intro text
Dim objRec, sql, introtext
sql="SELECT * FROM hometext WHERE home_id = 1"
set objRec=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec.Open sql, "dsn=databasename"
introtext = Replace(objRec("home_introtext"), vbCrLf, "<br />")

' Get the 5 newest news items
Dim objRec2, sql2, newstext
sql2="SELECT TOP 5 news_date, news_text FROM news ORDER BY news_date DESC"
set objRec2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec2.Open sql2, "dsn=databasename"

' Get all images to appear to page
Dim objRec3, sql3
sql3="SELECT * FROM homeimages ORDER BY homeimage_date DESC"
set objRec3=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec3.Open sql3, "dsn=databasename"

' Get the next 5 events from the current date
Dim objRec4, sql4
sql4="SELECT TOP 5 event_date, event_name FROM events WHERE event_date >= " &         niceDateAccess(Date()) & " ORDER BY event_date"
set objRec4=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec4.Open sql4, "dsn=databasename"
%>
```

I'm not sure how it all connects, I'm not much of a scripter.

Any (dumbed down) help would be appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: The database is sat in the 'private' folder in the root folder on the server.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12704479/447356) is correct. Have the first three lines from that answer as-is just changing the path to your database file then change `"dsn=databasename"` to `conob` throughout your whole code, for example: `objRec.Open sql, conob` and it will cause the code use the DSN-less connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code. Change your database name and tablefield name

```
set conob = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conob.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conob.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & server.MapPath("YourDatabaseName.mdb")
Set rsuni = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlStr="select * from Student_Entry"

rsuni.open sqlStr,conob
```

You must give full access to your database by which user you are logged on.

Comment: Thanks for that, although I'm not sure where that code needs to go and what it's replacing. If you could explain a bit more I'd really appreciate it. I'm not familiar with this coding style so if you could explain how to implement it for a dummy that'd be good! :)

Comment: @user1607021, the main difference is that your code above doesn't use an explicit connection object. Polin's code here does use an explicit ADO connection object which is opened using a connection string. This makes it so you do not need a DSN. I always avoid DSN's in everything I program, even local client applications in MS Access. DSNless connections offer far more flexibility and much less headache.

Comment: I have tried the code above, but I keep getting numberous error messages 'Object Require: 'objRec'.'

Here is my code:<br /><br />

set conob = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")<br />
conob.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"<br />
conob.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & server.MapPath("private/tvr.mdb")<br />
Set rsuni = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")<br />
sqlStr="SELECT * FROM hometext WHERE home_id = 1"<br />
objRec.Open sql, conob

Comment: just write database name like server.MapPath("tvr.mdb") . make sure the user has the full permission to access it.